# NicEdit não funcionando em outras textareas

Tags: php, html, textarea, nicedit

Estou criando uma espécie de fórum no site do meu cliente. Nesse fórum, pra fazer as perguntas e comentários, obviamente usam-se TextAreas.

Contudo, estou utilizado a classe NicEdit pra transformar meus textareas com opção de tipo de letra, tamanho, inserção de imagens e links etc. Só que a página possui duas textareas com ids "postar" e comentar". E só está funcionando a textarea "postar". Tive que colocar o código assim:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByName("postar");

    for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++)
     {
        var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
        myNicEditor.panelInstance(textareas[i]);

     }

    //var textareas2 = document.getElementsByName("comentar");

    //for(var i=0;i<textareas2.length;i++)
    // {
    //    var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
    //    myNicEditor.panelInstance(textareas2[i]);

    // }
});
</script>
```

Assim, minhas textareas de comentários estão normais. O que será que eu poderia fazer pra habilitar as textareas de comentários normalmente com o NicEdit?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione uma `class` nas `textarea` que vc quer instanciar o editor:

```
<textarea class="meueditor" name="postar"></textarea>
<textarea class="meueditor" name="comentar"></textarea>
```

Depois é só simplificar o código buscando pela nome da `class`:

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByClassName("meueditor");
    var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
    for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++)
    {
        myNicEditor.panelInstance(textareas[i]);
    }
});
```

Não precisa incluir var `myNicEditor = new nicEditor();` dentro do loop `for`. Basta invocá-lo 1 vez.